# Music from other apps stop when react native app is opening

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have created a new project. After running 'pod install' and launching the app, it opens successfully. However, when my other app (Spotify), playing music in the background, is interrupted.

If I open the React Native app and then attempt to play Spotify music while keeping the React Native app in the background, it works fine. The issue only occurs the first time the React Native app is opened.

Note: This is only happening in iOS, in Android its working fine.

More details
`https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4189111`

It should work without interrupting other music player app

Comment: The URL https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4189111 returns a 404

Comment: It should be https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/41891

Comment: They closed your issue due to the version of RN you are using being old.  Consider trying with the most recent version?  A LOT changes between versions of RN (and of Expo -- use Expo!)

Comment: @GregFenton I am still facing this issue in react-native-youtube-iframe after video stopped inside iframe.